# Unable to use pyspark in Jupyter on Windows

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have scoured the Internet and stackoverflow to figure out how to install Pyspark and use it in Jupyter Notebooks on Windows, but come at a dead end. I followed instructions provided by blogs such as these: https://medium.com/big-data-engineering/how-to-install-apache-spark-2-x-in-your-pc-e2047246ffc3.

Main issues:

- When I type "pyspark" on the command line, I see the error "The system cannot find the path specified." I have set environment variables, restarted my computer multiple times, and re-checked all the directories where Spark, winutils.exe and JDK are installed. Nothing worked.
- I have installed the pyspark and findspark packages in Anaconda. A call to findspark.find() displays the folder where Spark is installed, but when I try to initialize a Spark session in Jupyter, the cell keeps running until I interrupt the kernel.

I have installed the following:

1. Java version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16
2. Spark 3.5.1 for Hadoop 3
3. Winutils for Hadoop 3 and saved in the bin folder of the Spark installation

What am I missing?

## **Code and results**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
```

'C:\Users\\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3'

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("HelloWorld").getOrCreate()   #Execution gets stuck here
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

### After interrupting the kernel...

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 3
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 3 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("HelloWorld").getOrCreate()
      4 sc = spark.sparkContext

File ~\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:497, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    495     sparkConf.set(key, value)
    496 # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 497 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    498 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    499 # by all sessions.
    500 session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)

File ~\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\context.py:515, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    513 with SparkContext._lock:
    514     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 515         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    516     assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    517     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File ~\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\context.py:201, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls, memory_profiler_cls)
    195 if gateway is not None and gateway.gateway_parameters.auth_token is None:
    196     raise ValueError(
    197         "You are trying to pass an insecure Py4j gateway to Spark. This"
    198         " is not allowed as it is a security risk."
    199     )
--> 201 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    202 try:
    203     self._do_init(
    204         master,
    205         appName,
   (...)
    215         memory_profiler_cls,
    216     )

File ~\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\context.py:436, in SparkContext._ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    434 with SparkContext._lock:
    435     if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 436         SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    437         SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    439     if instance:

File ~\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py:104, in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    102 # Wait for the file to appear, or for the process to exit, whichever happens first.
    103 while not proc.poll() and not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 104     time.sleep(0.1)
    106 if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
    107     raise PySparkRuntimeError(
    108         error_class="JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED",
    109         message_parameters={},
    110     )

KeyboardInterrupt:
```